# Set text from list to Text Widget flutter

Tags: list, flutter, dart

I'm trying to set quotes from list to Text widget but i am facing this problem

The argument type 'List<Iterable>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

this is my code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myAppState createState() => _myAppState();
}

class _myAppState extends State<myApp> {
  List<String> quotesList = [
    "The secret of getting ahead is getting started",
    "Only the paranoid survive",
    "It’s hard to beat a person who never gives up.",
    "Never Had luck never needed it"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
          title: Text("Quotes"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: [quotesList.map((e) => Text(e))].toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: just remove [] in children  ,like this  children: quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),

Comment: another thing the class name should be with upperCase in First Lettre, myApp => MyApp :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to wrap the list with '[' and  ']'

```
Column(
   children: quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
),
```

And if you want to add more widgets, you can use like this

```
Column(
    children: quotesList.map<Widget>((e) => Text(e)).toList()
        ..addAll([
            Container() //You can use addAll method and add some juicy widgets
    ]),
),
```

Comment: Thanks it 's  working , but what if i want to add more widgets in this column ?

Comment: You can use the spread operator within your column, it looks a lot cleaner and you don't have to use an add all method

Answer (score 1):

Here is another (easy) approach.

Add this function to your current class -

```
List<Widget> getTextWidgets() {
  List<Widget> _widgets = [];
  for(int i=0;i<quotesList.length;i++) {
    _widgets.add(
      Text(quotesList[i])
    );
  }
  return _widgets;
}
```

And simply call it like -

```
body: Column(
  children: getTextWidgets(),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove [] from the quotesList -

```
quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
```

This might fix your issue -

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(myApp());
}

class myApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _myAppState createState() => _myAppState();
}

class _myAppState extends State<myApp> {
  List<String> quotesList = [
    "The secret of getting ahead is getting started",
    "Only the paranoid survive",
    "It’s hard to beat a person who never gives up.",
    "Never Had luck never needed it"
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          centerTitle: true,
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,
          title: Text("Quotes"),
        ),
        body: Column(
          children: quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, you need to remove the `[` and `]`, to look like this

```dart
quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)).toList()
```

If you want to add more widgets, you can use the spread operator

```dart
Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    // you can add more widgets here
    ...quotesList.map((e) => Text(e)),
    // you can add more widgets here too
  ],
)
```